# Reassigning references to elements based on state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have an array that I am looping through to create div elements, and based on which of these divs is 'active' (derived from state) I want them to have the ref property. This ref is also the parameter for a hook I'm using that adds an onclick listener to that ref. This works ok when the first div is active, however when my state changes to make the 2nd div active, the onclick listener isn't active on the 2nd div. Any idea on how I can resolve this?

Component file:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

const { element } = useClick(ref);

return (
        <div style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
            {cards.map((card, index) => (
                <div
                    {...(index === active ? { ref } : { 'aria-hidden': 'true' })}
                >
                    <Card>
                        <div className={styles.title}>{card}</div>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
```

Custom hook:

```
const useClick = (
    element: RefObject<HTMLElement>
): {
    element: RefObject<HTMLElement>;
} => {
    const onClick = (): void => {
        console.log('clicked');
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!element.current) {
            return undefined;
        }
        element.current.addEventListener('click', onClick);

        return (): void => {
            element.current?.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
        };
    }, [element]);

    return { element };
};

export default useClick;
```

I'd expect the onclick handler to be removed from the first element when it is no longer active and for this to be moved to the 2nd div in the loop. I tried an approach with using an array of refs so that each div had a unique ref but wasn't able to achieve this when using the ref index in the parameter of my custom hook. I can see my state is changing (active) correctly but I've redacted this code as its quite long and complex with IP and doesn't seem to coincide with the problem

Comment: Why are you using a ref and on eventListener instead of having the onCLick directly on your div?

Comment: This is just a stripped down version as I didn't want to include all the other code that wasn't relevant to the problem. There's all sorts of other event handlers I'm planning to use like mousedown and mouseenter but want to see why this event handler doesn't reassign itself first

Answer (score 1):

If all you care about is the `onClick`, use it directly without a `ref` and setting it manually in `useEffect`:

```
<div 
  {...(index === active 
    ? { onClick } 
    : { 'aria-hidden': 'true' })
  }
>
```

### Why doesn't it work?

The `ref` that you're using is an object reference, which have the `current` property (`ref = { current }`). While `current` changes according to the `div` it's used on `ref` stays the same, and the `useEffect` is not triggered.

Change the dependencies to look at `element.current`, and also add `onClick` because it's a dependency of `useEffect` as well:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!element.current) {
        return undefined;
    }
    element.current.addEventListener('click', onClick);

    return (): void => {
        element.current?.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    };
}, [element.current, onClick]);
```

Another option is to use a function ref with `useState`:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState(0);
const [ref, setRef] = useState(null); // the state is used as ref

const { element } = useClick(ref);

<div
  // use setRef as a function ref
  {...(index === active ? { ref: setRef } : { 'aria-hidden': 'true' })}
>

// in your custom hook
useEffect(() => {
    // in this case element doesn't have current
    if (!element) return undefined;
    
    element?.addEventListener('click', onClick);

    return (): void => {
      element?.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    };
}, [element]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding onClick as a dependency to the useEffect did the trick

Comment: Although it works, why do you need the ref, and don't just use `onClick` prop on the divs?